# php fopen failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, fopen

i'm having problem writing to a text file using php. this might sound simple but i've set the file owner and group to apache/root, permission to 777 and i'm still unable to write to file. i'm running centos with php 5.3.8.

```
====================
New info
====================

semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd | grep rw
/var/lib/drupal(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_rw_t:s0 
/var/spool/gosa(/.*)?                              all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_rw_t:s0 
/var/lib/bugzilla(/.*)?                            all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_bugzilla_script_rw_t:s0 
/var/spool/viewvc(/.*)?                            all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_rw_t:s0
```

Comment: SELinux is very likely blocking the file write, if the directory containing it doesn't have a rw context.

Comment: You might need to `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/file`

Comment: i've set the dir containing the file to 777 and to root/apache as well.. but still not working

Comment: To test this theory, as root run `setenforce 0` then try to run the script. If it succeeds, SELinux is the problem. Turn it back on with `setenforce 1`

Comment: yes it works after setting to 0..i did the following and got the following error: chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t test.txt
chcon: failed to change context of test.txt to root:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t: Invalid argument

Comment: so i read and SELinux is some kind of security policy thingy.. how do i enable write to file and keeping the policy right??

Comment: You may not have that context available in your CentOS version.  do `semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd | grep rw` to see what rw contexts are available for httpd.

Comment: We are trying to set the correct context for your writable file so that SELinux can remain enabled.

Comment: Oh, also try the `httpd_cache_t` context:  `chcon -t httpd_cache_t test.txt`.  It may work

Comment: hey michael, i've edited my Q to include the results from semanage fcontext -l | grep httpd | grep rw

Comment: erm chcon -t httpd_cache_t test.txt doesn't work tho

Comment: do `man httpd_selinux` and search for `rw` with `/rw<Enter>` You might need to use `httpd_sys_script_rw_t` if that is the only rw context available on your system

Comment: hey tks michael. i'm still having trouble but i'll look into it further..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To allow the directory to be r/w, i used the [`chcon`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chcon1.html) command to add the [`httpd_sys_script_rw_t`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache) type to the directory and anything under it:

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t <directory>`

The `-R` flag makes the command recursive.

The `-t` flag sets the extended attribute on the file to the specified file context. In this case the httpd file context `httpd_sys_script_rw_t` which is used when:

> you want httpd_sys_script_exec_t scripts to read/write the data, and disallow other non sys scripts from access.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate file contexts to use for allowing HTTPd to write to disk (as well as booleans for other operations) are described in the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page.